# how to remove default border and how to anchor jtable's column header?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, border, jtabbedpane

[image: this is my question]

Hello.

i want to delete scollpane's border and

i don't want to allow column's header move it when i drag.

please save me

thanks in advance

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

    class mf extends JFrame{

        public mf(){

            this.setSize(444, 444);
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            Object[] haha = new Object[]{"list"};
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(haha, 0);

            model.addRow(new Object[]{"don't try hit me and hit me"});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{"free your mind"});
            JTable wow = new JTable(model);
            wow.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

            JScrollPane jesus = new JScrollPane(wow);


            JTabbedPane jt = new JTabbedPane();
            jt.addTab("no way", jesus);

            this.add(jt, BorderLayout.NORTH);

           this.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
    public class Test extends JFrame{
      public static void main(String[] args){
          new mf();}}
```

Answer (score 1):

To forbid moving of column header, you can use `wow.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);`.

For removing `Border` use:

```
JScrollPane jesus = new JScrollPane(wow);
jesus.setBorder(null);
```